# I'm looking to have a Folder recognise new files being saved into it and then copy new files into a collated folder

Tags: applescript, automator

In MacOS i want a folder action to trigger when i place a new file into a subfolder. The action should grab a newly added file to the folder and copy it to another folder where all the latest files are collated and can be viewed together. I also want the script to delete any old version of the same file it copies across to the collated folder. The trouble is the file names are slightly dfferent as they have a version number in them. The version number is defined as "v01a" to start with but can change to "v01b" or "v01e" or "v02a" or "v03c".
So if a file called "1234_ProjectName_Image01_COMP_v01a.jpg" already exists and a new file called "1234_ProjectName_Image01_COMP_v01b.jpg" is added the the file called "1234_ProjectName_Image01_COMP_v01a.jpg" needs to be deleted from the destination folder.

I've tried a few times to get started in automator but never really get the pieces in place for it to be useful.

(SOURCE)

- Dailies/_Internal
  Dailies/_Internal/Image01/1234_ProjectName_Image01_COMP_v01a.jpg
  Dailies/_Internal/Image02/1234_ProjectName_Image02_COMP_v01a.jpg
  Dailies/_Internal/Image03/1234_ProjectName_Image03_COMP_v01a.jpg

(DESTINATION)

- Dailies/_Latest
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image01_COMP_v01a.jpg
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image02_COMP_v01a.jpg
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image03_COMP_v01a.jpg

If a new file is added called

- Dailies/_Internal/Image01/1234_ProjectName_Image01_COMP_v02a.jpg

then this file is copied from its source folder and put into the Destination folder.

(DESTINATION)

- Dailies/_Latest
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image01_COMP_v01a.jpg
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image01_COMP_v02a.jpg
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image02_COMP_v01a.jpg
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image03_COMP_v01a.jpg

Here there is already an image with the same name except the version number so the script should also delete the old file leaving me with.

(DESTINATION)

- Dailies/_Latest
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image01_COMP_v02a.jpg
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image02_COMP_v01a.jpg
  Dailies/_Latest/1234_ProjectName_Image03_COMP_v01a.jpg

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[Screengrab of my very basic automator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRmxb.png)

Comment: A folder action doesn’t watch subfolders - it needs to be attached to each and every watched folder.  Is it just the name part after the last underscore that changes, and does the added item always sort after an existing one?

Comment: Oh ok, thats a shame, so there is no easy way to impliment it to a folder with subfolders? I could have 20 or 30 subfolders.
Yes its just the name part after the last underscore that changes.
Not sure what you mean by the last sentance. It could either be the number or the last letter that changes.

Its would start at _v01a, then itterate to _v01b, then _v01c. It might jump to _v01f. It could then jump to _v02a, then _v02c, then _v02f, then _v03b. It would never go backwards down the numbers or letters though

Comment: You can manually or programmatically add folder actions as new subfolders are created.  Yes, I was referring to the numbers and letters in the version always increasing, so new and old could just be sorted to determine the one to keep.

Comment: How would I programmatically add new folder actions then?

Yes the version would only ever increase

Comment: It is from the System Events Hidden Suite - `tell application "System Events" to attach action to theFolder using theScript`.  How are you selecting the folder to add?

Comment: I was having to apply it as a right click and use folder actions setup but it wasn't great. Do you know of a better way?

Comment: You haven’t posted any code of what you have done so far so I can’t tell, but it can be added programmatically according to however you are adding the subfolders.

Comment: I don't really have anything that works, i've researched a little and tried to start a few times with automator but haven't got passed copying a file from one location to another using a folder action which doesn't account for any versioning and doesn't delete the old files in the destination folder meaning its pretty useless.

Folder Action - Folder added to "internals"
-Filter Finder items, any content, contains .jpg
-copy finder items To: "_Latest"

What i have accounts for no variables or a relative destination folder at the same folder structure level as the source.

Comment: The Subfolders are added by a script from photoshop when a new image is saved out which doesn't already have a corresponding folder

Comment: @red_menace i put a screen grab of the very basic automator i have in the original post.